# SCP gives "File or directory not found"

Tags: linux, macos, command, scp

I am having an issue. I am using the SCP command to transfer files from my desktop of my mac osx too my virtual server. The thing is I ran the command and successfully transferred one file from my desktop over to the server, no problem.

So i use the same command which is:
`scp filename_I_want_to_transfer user@serverip:`

So basically that looks like `scp test user@10.0.0.0:`
(I just used random IP for example)

Anyways on the second file I'm trying to transfer which is also in the document format I continually get "**No such file or directory**".
Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe because "test" doesn't exist?

Comment: Well the file is sitting on my desktop and it is actually named "dev" I just used the test for an example. I am sure that the file exists because it is sitting on my desktop and it is 27.97 GB file. So thats definately not the problem. the path is /Users/nokeys/desktop just so you know

Comment: Actually form the example command given one can only conclude that `test` did not exist in the current directory. You should give an *exact* example what failed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To send a file from the local host to another server use:

```
scp /path/to/file.doc user@<IP or hostname>:/path/to/where/it/should/go/
```

To get a file from another server to the local host use:

```
scp user@<IP or hostname>:/path/to/file.doc /path/to/where/it/should/go/
```

This is the format I reliably use for copying from a location to another location. You can use absolute path, or relative/special character path, such as

```
scp suiterdev@fakeserver:~/folder/file .
```

which would be "Securely copy the file named `file` in `$HOME/folder/` (`~` equivalent to `~suiterdev` or `$HOME`) as user `suiterdev` from host `fakeserver` to the current directory (`.`).

However you'll have to take care that special characters (see the shell's filename expansion mechanism) used for the remote path are not expanded locally (because that typically is *not* what you want).

Comment: This is still returning the same error, and im sure i typed everytihng correct. Even tried it 3 times. Would it make a difference if the file im trying to copy is technically not a .doc even though it is. The file is a packages base box for vagrant. Meaning it is technically like a virtual machine, that i am trying to copy to a base bare bones virtual server.

Comment: Linux is case sensitive, are you certain you are typing the path and file name exactly as it is on the server you're trying to get it from? If anything is different at all, different case, extension on the name in one place but not the other, the utility will not recognize what you are asking for.

Comment: Yes, im certain everything is exactly as spelled. Please see below this is exactly how im typing it. One thing to note is im trying to go from my desktop of my mac to a virtual server. Im typing these commands in on the terminal on my mac.  

scp steven@10.10.10.10:/Users/nokeys/Desktop/dev /home/steven

I used a fake ip address by the way.. so the ip address isnt the problem. Other than that that is exactly as i typed it.. and the error is always exactly: /Users/nokeys/Desktop/dev: No such file or directory. 
Not sure what is causing this file to fail when my other file on the desktop worked

Comment: Ahh, figured it out.. instead of doing scp (server credentials) as i was doing... You have to do 

scp (path of file on desktop) space servercredentials then path on server to put it. 

So scp steven@10.10.10.10:/Users/nokeys/Desktop/dev /home/steven

Should have looked like scp /Users/nokeys/Desktop/dev steven@10.10.10.10:/home/steven 

That was the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Well for me am using Ubuntu 15.10 and this is what worked for me.

**scp user@host.com:path/to/file.txt /home/to/local/folder/**

instead of

**scp user@host.com:/path/to/file.txt /home/to/local/folder/**

**Note** that after user@host.com host i do not include the forward slash i immediately append the folder after the **":"**

Scp uses the *target user's home directory* as default directory (as a relative path), so when you need an *absolute path*, then use one (starting with a slash (`/`)).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is way too late for this to help you, but it may help others who had the same problem as me
for my case my pc is set up to use backwards slash `"\"` instead of forward slash `"/"` and changing to backwards slashes removed the errors

But I only had to change the slashes to backward slashes on my pc's directory as my raspberry pi uses forward slashes.
I know it is a bit confusing but it worked for me.

Comment: Traditionally slash (`/`) had also worked in MS-DOS and MS-Windows system calls, while commands and GUIs often insist on backslash (`\`) being used. Sometimes you need to double the backslash even when backslash works as escape character (C programmers know that).